# display html inside spacebar variable

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

A Meteor server side code generates text like `var text = line one <br> line two` and on the client side there is a template with its helper to inject that text in a spacebar `{{text}}`. But what gets rendered on the page is the text including the html markup.

How can I get the template to display it correctly with the line break instead of the string `<br>`? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use triple braces:

```
{{{html}}}
```

Comment: I will have to find a way to handle security if to use the triple braces. ;)